# This for array colllision function doesn't work with anything but first object in array

Tags: actionscript-3

For some reason, this simple simple loop is totally broken.
(characterSheet is my character Class, it's just a movieClip with some extra functionality)
(hitBox, is basically a square movieclip)

Anyway: every time hitBox make contact with a characterSheet in a different order than they were created: Nothing happens.  The program only seems to be listening to collisions that are made with o2[0].  As soon as another hitBox is created, it pushes the last one out of o2[0] and the last one becomes totally useless.
What's super weird is that I can hit characterSheets in any order I like....

```
    public function collisions(o1:Array, o2:Array)
    {
        if((o1.lenght>=0)&&(o2.length>=0)){
            for (var i = 0; i < o1.length; i++)
            {
                var ob1 = o1[i];
                for (var f = 0; f < o1.length; f++)
                {
                    var ob2 = o2[f];

                    if (ob1 is characterSheet)
                    {   if (ob2.hitTestObject(ob1))
                            {
                                var right:Boolean = true;
                                if (ob1.x < hitBox(ob2).origin.x)
                                    right = false;
                                characterSheet(ob1).specialDamage(hitBox(ob2).damageType, hitBox(ob2).damage, right);
                                }}}}}}
```

Also it might be somewhat helpful to see the function for creating a new hitBox

```
    public function SpawnHitBox(targeted, following, atype, xoff, yoff, ... args)
    {
        var newHitBox = new hitBox(targeted, following, atype, xoff, yoff, args);
        badCollisionObjects.push(newHitBox);
        arraydictionary[newHitBox] = badCollisionObjects;
        addChild(newHitBox);

    }
```

Comment: Should it be `for (var f = 0; f < o2.length; f++)`... just skimmed the code, that seemed to stand out. If there is only one object in `o1` array, then you will get a single collision only

Comment: HAHA! Stupid mistake, wasted half the day trying to fix it, thanks...Edit:Didn't fix the problem.  Though I did find a solution that works for some reason: I have just made it so that when hitBox's are done resizing-animating etc.. They fly 9000 pixels off screen and patiently wait to be collected until the badCollisionObjects.length>=10 when they are spliced.

Comment: ;), in that case, I'll put that as the answer

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be: `for (var f = 0; f < o2.length; f++)`... just skimmed the code, that seemed to stand out. If there is only one object in o1 array, then you will get a single collision only

Comment: As I just put up in an edit:this was a problem in the code, but unfortunately It didn't fix the entire problem.  Thanks so much though.